# how to download as a rar file

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I'm trying to download mods for Minecraft, and I have Forge. I see all the youtubers having their mods as RAR files, and I want that too. But when I download my mods, it downloads them as ZIP files instead of RAR files. How do I download as RAR files because it is always a ZIP file. Do I have to do some other steps?

I have WinRAR, and 7zip, but why does my computer choose 7zip? I have already tried using Youtube and I couldn't find anything. I have tried right clicking on things but do I have to extract the file?

Comment: rar, zip, 7z, tar, tgz and others are just different formats of created archives. Each has its specifications, but at the very basic level, it doesn't matter much which one you will use. The purpose is to put some files into one archive (and possibly compress them) for easier sharing. The only thing that you have to do is just to extract them.

Comment: ok i was just wondering if i was missing out on something

Comment: I can't think of much more to add, I'll put it up as the answer

Answer (score 3):

rar, zip, 7z, tar, tgz and others are just different formats of created archives. Each has its specifications, but at the very basic level, it doesn't matter much which one you will use. The purpose is to put some files into one archive (and possibly compress them) for easier sharing. The only thing that you have to do is just to extract them.

Comment: Spent so much time on pictures that I didn't see your answer lol

Comment: Still, pictures are nice. :-D

Comment: Yep, that's true :D lol
Also, you answered first, you get a UP first :P

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much difference between zip and rar files...

BUT, you have to set WinRAR as the default program for .rar and .zip files, then decompile the files, and then compile them again as a .rar file.

Still, as I said, I don't understand why you would want a .rar file.

[image: Setting Default Program]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]